# How to extend/overwrite an exported type in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm using `@fortawesome` and `@fortawesome/react-fontawesome`.  `@fortawesome/fontawesome-common-types` defines `IconDefinition` as

```ts
export interface IconLookup {
  prefix: IconPrefix;
  // IconName is defined in the code that will be generated at build time and bundled with this file.
  iconName: IconName;
}

export interface IconDefinition extends IconLookup {
  icon: any[];
}

export type IconProp = IconLookup | /*...*/;

export type IconName = /* a lot of concatenated strings */;
```

`@fortawesome/react-fontawesome` defines

```ts
export function FontAwesomeIcon(props: Props): JSX.Element;
export interface Props {
    icon: IconProp;
    /* ... */
}
```

I wanted to add my own SVGs and use them in the `icon` property of `<FontAwesomeIcon />`.

```ts
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';

type CustomIconName = 'myCustomIcon' /* | ... */;
interface CustomIconDefinition extends Pick<IconDefinition, Exclude<keyof IconDefinition, 'iconName'>> {
    prefix: 'fab',
    iconName: CustomIconName;
}

const MyCustomIcon: CustomIconDefinition = /* ... */;

export default function() {
    let icon: any = MyCustomIcon;
    return <FontAwesomeIcon icon={icon} />;
}
```

This works so long as `icon` is of type `any`.

I'd like to remove `CustomIconDefinition` and overwrite or extend the `IconName` definition to include `MyCustomIcon`.

I thought to do something like:

```ts
import { IconName as VanillaIconName } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-common-types';
declare module "@fortawesome/fontawesome-common-types" {
    export type IconName = VanillaIconName | MyCustomIcon;
}
```

This results in `Duplicate identifier 'IconName'.  index.d.ts(16,13): 'IconName' was also declared here.`  I suspect even if I get around this, it's going to have an error because `IconName = VanillaIconName` introduces a circular definition.

I also thought to overwrite the `FontAwesomeIcon` definition, but I didn't get far on that one because `icon: IconProp` is several types deep.  I suppose I could create my own `CustomFontAwesomeIcon extends FontAwesomeIcon`, but this isn't ideal.

Comment: This might be helpful. github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28078 I spent 20-minutes trying to get it to work,though, without success. Your mileage may be better.

Comment: Unless you can find a hack like that, it is not possible to augment a type alias nor to change the type of an interface property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It occurred to me 2.5 years later that while `type` augmentation declaration merging isn't possible, `interface` declaration merging is.

I haven't tested this code yet, as I don't even remember which project I needed this for, but I should™ be able to augment `Props` of `@fortawesome/react-fontawesome`.

```ts
import { IconProp } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-common-types';

declare module '@fortaweome/react-fontawesome' {
  export interface Props {
    icon: CustomIconProp;
  }
}

type CustomIconName = 'myCustomIcon' /* | ... */;

interface CustomIconProp extends Omit<IconProp, 'iconName'> {
  iconName: CustomIconName;
}
```

This doesn't solve the question posed in the title, but does solve the problem I had.

---

Note: there is an uber-hacky way to solve the problem posed by the title, by overwriting the package's declaration file using [`patch-package`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package).  Regrettably, I've taken this approach before for a dependency version I was bound to, but which future versions fixed the type I needed.